# iOS 8.1.3 breaks Safari credit card scanning

Tags: ios, safari, ocr

Last night my iPhone 4S was running iOS 8.1.2 and safari credit card scanning was working perfectly OK.  This morning I upgraded to iOS 8.1.3 and the functionality is now broken.

I created an HTML file containing a simple form asking users to input their credit number, expiry month and expiry year. If you clicked in the credit card field an additional option to scan your card appeared and if you tapped it you could scan your credit card and safari would employ in-built OCR to recognise your card number and auto fill the field. This is no longer working in iOS 8.1.3, as in when I tap on the credit card field, the keyboard option no longer appears.

[Here's a link to the test site](http://kaustav.uk.com/credit.html) I created that WAS WORKING last night and not working after the OS upgrade.

Notes:

- YES I do have a valid SSL cert on the site (it's NOT self signed)
- YES I've set the input elements ID to the correct names (check the page source)

Any advise from anyone on what might have changed here?

Comment: Interestingly, it should be noted that the SSL certificate I have on my domain is a 128bit TLS 1.2 and does not have a public audit records. I wonder if between iOS 8.1.2 and iOS 8.1.3 Apple of increased the SSL cert encryption threshold? e.g. to 256bit?

Comment: FWIW my iPhone which is still on iOS 8.1 doesn't prompt to scan a credit card either on that webpage.

Comment: @grgarside thanks for the feedback. Most intriguing. I will have to quadruple check my code and make sure I'm not smoking the wrong thing! ;-)

Comment: Problem resolved. It looks like between iOS 8.1 and 8.1.3 the valid input type for a form field has changed from "number", as I had it before, to "tel" which is what I've changed it to now.